# Can't GPU render with NVIDIA GTX 1650 mobile

Tags: rendering, gpu

[image]

I'm using linux mint 20 and it says No compatible GPUS found for path tracing. I am using blender 2.83. Here is the system info.

````
=====================================
= Blender 2.83.1 System Information =
=====================================


Blender:
=====================================

version: 2.83.1, branch: master, commit date: 2020-06-25 09:47, hash: 8289fc688b3e, type: Release
build date: 2020-06-25, 10:29:26
platform: Linux
binary path: '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/blender'
build cflags:  -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wundef -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Wformat-signedness -Wnonnull -Wuninitialized -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable  -fuse-ld=gold -std=gnu11   -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -msse2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
build cxxflags:  -Wredundant-decls -Wall -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-compare -Wlogical-op -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtype-limits -Werror=return-type -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wpointer-arith -Wunused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wformat-signedness -Wuninitialized -Wundef -Wmissing-declarations  -fuse-ld=gold -std=c++11   -msse -pipe -fPIC -funsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -msse2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
build linkflags:  -Wl,--version-script='/home/sources/buildbot-worker-linux_centos7/linux_lts_283/blender.git/source/creator/blender.map'
build system: CMake

Python:
=====================================

version: 3.7.4 (default, Oct  8 2019, 15:23:02)  [GCC 6.3.1 20170216 (Red Hat 6.3.1-3)]
file system encoding: utf-8:surrogateescape
paths:
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/startup'
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/modules'
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/python/lib/python37.zip'
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/python/lib/python3.7'
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload'
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages'
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/freestyle/modules'
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/modules'
    '/home/prateek/.config/blender/2.83/scripts/addons/modules'
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons'

Python (External Binary):
=====================================

binary path: '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/python/bin/python3.7m'
version: Python 3.7.4

Directories:
=====================================

scripts:
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/modules'
    '/home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts'
user scripts: '/home/prateek/.config/blender/2.83/scripts'
pref scripts: None
datafiles: '/home/prateek/.config/blender/2.83/datafiles/'
config: '/home/prateek/.config/blender/2.83/config/'
scripts : '/home/prateek/.config/blender/2.83/scripts/'
autosave: '/home/prateek/.config/blender/2.83/autosave/'
tempdir: '/tmp/blender_FLCA8W/'

FFmpeg:
=====================================

avcodec:   '58, 18, 100'
avdevice:  '58,  3, 100'
avformat:  '58, 12, 100'
avutil:    '56, 14, 100'
swscale:   ' 5,  1, 100'

SDL:
=====================================

Version: 2.0.10
Loading method: dynamically loaded by Blender (WITH_SDL_DYNLOAD=ON)

Other Libraries:
=====================================

OpenColorIO:  1,  1,  0
OpenImageIO:  1,  8, 13
OpenShadingLanguage:  1, 10,  9
OpenSubdiv:  0,  0,  0
OpenVDB:  7,  0,  0
Alembic:  1,  7, 12
USD:  0, 19, 11

OpenGL:
=====================================

renderer:   'Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)'
vendor:     'Intel'
version:    '4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.4'
extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth
    GL_AMD_depth_clamp_separate
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend
    GL_AMD_gpu_shader_int64
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect
    GL_AMD_performance_monitor
    GL_AMD_pinned_memory
    GL_AMD_query_buffer_object
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture
    GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax
    GL_AMD_texture_texture4
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility
    GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility
    GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility
    GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays
    GL_ARB_base_instance
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended
    GL_ARB_buffer_storage
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_clear_texture
    GL_ARB_clip_control
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage
    GL_ARB_compute_shader
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer
    GL_ARB_copy_image
    GL_ARB_cull_distance
    GL_ARB_debug_output
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp
    GL_ARB_derivative_control
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced
    GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location
    GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions
    GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader_interlock
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary
    GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image
    GL_ARB_gl_spirv
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader5
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex
    GL_ARB_indirect_parameters
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range
    GL_ARB_multi_bind
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2
    GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile
    GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_point_sprite
    GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp
    GL_ARB_post_depth_coverage
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex
    GL_ARB_query_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior
    GL_ARB_robustness
    GL_ARB_sample_shading
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map
    GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters
    GL_ARB_shader_ballot
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding
    GL_ARB_shader_clock
    GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters
    GL_ARB_shader_group_vote
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store
    GL_ARB_shader_image_size
    GL_ARB_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_shader_precision
    GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export
    GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_shader_subroutine
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod
    GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack
    GL_ARB_shading_language_include
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing
    GL_ARB_spirv_extensions
    GL_ARB_stencil_texturing
    GL_ARB_sync
    GL_ARB_tessellation_shader
    GL_ARB_texture_barrier
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array
    GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic
    GL_ARB_texture_float
    GL_ARB_texture_gather
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels
    GL_ARB_texture_query_lod
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle
    GL_ARB_texture_rg
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui
    GL_ARB_texture_stencil8
    GL_ARB_texture_storage
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle
    GL_ARB_texture_view
    GL_ARB_timer_query
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev
    GL_ARB_viewport_array
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate
    GL_ATI_texture_float
    GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage
    GL_EXT_EGL_sync
    GL_EXT_abgr
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
    GL_EXT_demote_to_helper_invocation
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil
    GL_EXT_packed_float
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex
    GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch
    GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch_non_coherent
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix
    GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical
    GL_EXT_texture_array
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
    GL_EXT_texture_integer
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode
    GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent
    GL_EXT_texture_snorm
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle
    GL_EXT_timer_query
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra
    GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays
    GL_INTEL_conservative_rasterization
    GL_INTEL_performance_query
    GL_INTEL_shader_atomic_float_minmax
    GL_INTEL_shader_integer_functions2
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control
    GL_KHR_debug
    GL_KHR_no_error
    GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile
    GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior
    GL_KHR_robustness
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d
    GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y
    GL_MESA_pack_invert
    GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba
    GL_NV_compute_shader_derivatives
    GL_NV_conditional_render
    GL_NV_depth_clamp
    GL_NV_fragment_shader_interlock
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil
    GL_NV_texture_barrier
    GL_OES_EGL_image
    GL_S3_s3tc

Implementation Dependent OpenGL Limits:
=====================================

Maximum DrawElements Vertices:  3000
Maximum DrawElements Indices:   3000

GLSL:
Maximum Varying Floats: 128
Maximum Vertex Attributes:  16
Maximum Vertex Uniform Components:  16384
Maximum Fragment Uniform Components:    16384
Maximum Vertex Image Units: 32
Maximum Fragment Image Units:   32
Maximum Pipeline Image Units:   192

Cycles:
=====================================


CPU device capabilities: SSE2 SSE3 SSE41 AVX AVX2

OpenCL device capabilities:
No OpenCL platforms found

CUDA device capabilities:
No CUDA device found

Enabled add-ons:
=====================================

io_anim_bvh (version: (1, 0, 0), path: /home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_anim_bvh/__init__.py)
io_curve_svg (version: (), path: /home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_curve_svg/__init__.py)
io_mesh_ply (version: (1, 1, 0), path: /home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_mesh_ply/__init__.py)
io_mesh_stl (version: (1, 1, 3), path: /home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_mesh_stl/__init__.py)
io_mesh_uv_layout (version: (1, 1, 1), path: /home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_mesh_uv_layout/__init__.py)
io_scene_fbx (version: (4, 20, 3), path: /home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_scene_fbx/__init__.py)
io_scene_gltf2 (version: (1, 2, 75), path: /home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py)
io_scene_obj (version: (3, 8, 0), path: /home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_scene_obj/__init__.py)
io_scene_x3d (version: (2, 2, 5), path: /home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/io_scene_x3d/__init__.py)
cycles (version: (), path: /home/prateek/Blender/blender-2.83.1-linux64/2.83/scripts/addons/cycles/__init__.py)
```
````

Comment: Most of the  time issues like this are caused by problems with GPU drivers or them not being up to date. Maybe try other driver version.

Comment: are you installing blender from the file from blender.org?

Comment: I did install it from Blender.org which was supposed to be built with CUDA, I have yet to try other versions. It works perfectly fine in windows.